# findViewById(R.id.list_view); returning "null"

Tags: android

I am trying to display `ListView`.

I have created one `activity` , in `onCreate()` method I am launching one `AsyncTask` and in `onPostExecute()` method I am trying display `ListView` in that .

but `listView` object receiving null..

Below is the code snippet.

```
 protected void onPostExecute(KpiResponseObject kpiReportResponse) {
     ListView listView;
     listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
}
```

Here I'am receiving null in `listView` object.

I am suspecting this is the `context` problem , but not able figure out what exactly it is.

Comment: your `AsyncTask` is should be a inner class, so the inner class in which activity, the activity has the `R.id.list_view` view or not, and the activity used `setContentView` method or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you have `setContentView` in your `onCreate` and then have a `ListView` `list_view` defined in XML?

Answer (score 1):

The layout you are putting in the `setContentView()` doesn't have any view whose id is `list_view`.

Answer (score 1):

@brig this is almost 100% a context problem.  You should be calling the findViewByID from one of the overlying views.  An easy solution is just pass the context to this asynctask(I am assuming this is an asynctask of some sort).  In the constructor set a memeber

```
private Context mContext;

public myAsync(Context context){
  mContext = context;
}
```

then in you call

```
protected void onPostExecute(KpiResponseObject kpiReportResponse) {
     ListView listView;
     listView = (ListView) mContext.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
}
```

Comment: Why, onPostExecute gets called from the UI thread. And if the AsyncTask is nested into Activity then Activity's context is accessible from it.

Comment: @Alex but does it mean necessarily that it would have direct access to the same context, even if not an inner class definition?

Comment: The context can be accessible using **MyActivity.this** also

Comment: @Creator is that always reliable though, I have had some issues trying to use that?

Comment: No, not always. But most of the time it is. The issue might come in the inner and anonymous classes, however for AsyncTask, it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

There will be a two reason you may get null value one is doesn't defined setContentView(xml) and second from what context which your calling Asynctask. Check this both the things you wil l the things.